# Static Content Issue After few SOAP API calls

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

I have recently made a magento project live, with some customization. The client asked that they need to integrate Microsoft Navision with magento, for that they are using SOAP APIs (V1 and V2 both). There is a strange error that we are facing on Production. The SOAP API calls works fine but after few calls the URL for static content get changed e.g.

`http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/default/mytheme/images/abc.gif` it get converted to `/frontend/default/mytheme/images/abc.gif`. (yes `skin` is not there in the URL)

Same is happening with JS CSS and media images also. But As soon as we clear the cache it works well. Then again after few API calls it stops working.

This is a very odd Behavior, any help or direction is much much appreciated !